# How do you pronounce 0.1st percentile?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, percentile

I'm analyzing some out of range values that are either really high (above the 99.9th percentile) or really low (below the 0.1st percentile). How would you pronounce 0.1st percentile?

Comment: I'd say the "zero point one'th percentile" (as opposed to "zero point first")

Comment: I’d say *zero point first percentile* or use a paraphrase of some kind, e.g., *in the bottom tenth of a percent*. (There is no way on earth that I’d combine the cardinal number *one* with the ordinal suffix *-th*.)

Comment: Let’s have a fight, @BrianM.Scott . I always write “$(n-1)$-th” and read it “$n$ minus one’th”. But I emphatically agree with you on the virtue of paraphrase in this case.

Comment: @Lubin: And I always write ‘$(n-1)$-st’ and read it ‘$n$ minus first’. :-)

Comment: First tenth of a percentile (and 99.9 becomes the last tenth percentile correspondingly). :)

Comment: Why is everyone answering the poster's question in the comments?